# Why am I getting errors after initialization in Intellij IDEA sbt shell?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm having issues with the SBT shell in the Intellij IDEA.
I am running Windows 10 and have the latest versions of Scala, Intellij and SBT installed on my machine.
I created a small sample project called "Hello World."

When I open the "sbt shell" I get the following prompt in green:
(initalizing) >

I then get the following initialization messages:

[image: sbt shell Initialization messages]

After which I just see the ">" prompt in green.
If I try to run a simple command such as "sbtversion" I get an error saying unknown command.
[image: Errors in sbt shell]
It looks like the sbtshell never finishes initialization for some reason?

What is going on here?
What am I doing wrong?
Am I missing a step somewhere?

Thanks

Comment: As the error says, "sbtversion" isn't a command, "sbtVersion" and "version" are

Answer (score 0):

SBT is case sensitive.; Try using sbt**V**ersion instead of sbt**v**ersion.

Your shell seems to be fully initialized: the new lined
>

is Intellij's way of interacting with the shell prompt.